# visual editor eclipse

Tags: java

I downloaded eclipse Version: 3.5.0, Also visual editor seems to work, and now I decided to clean up a little project I had, then open the main.java with visual editor, but no GUI appears, do you know what I am missing?

How to see my GUI, if I execute it I get a panel and frame etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse uses .xml files to define layouts for GUI components. Therefore, you would have to recreate what you already have in an .xml file